# SSDT and Database Migrations

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, migration, sql-server-data-tools

Using SSDT in Visual Studio, I can create a database project, add tables, views, stored procs and I'm able to deploy to the server with no problem. However, I expect to see the scripts in the table **dbo._MigrationLog** but I don't see any records in the table unless I put a DDL or DML script in pre or post deployment. For .sql scripts outside of pre or post deployment scripts (i.e. scripts in the Table, Stored Procedures or Views folders), is there a way to log their deployment in the **dbo._MigrationLog**?

Comment: The _MigrationLog seems to be an artifact from ReadyRoll by Red-Gate. I've never seen that in any of the SSDT native functionality.  http://thedatabaseavenger.com/2016/12/readyroll-development/    SSDT works by comparing the project/dacpac to the target and making it the same. You can opt to generate a script if you want to see what it's doing and save that.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm actually not using ReadyRoll but a CI/CD tool developed by a third-party as I discovered this morning.Thanks for your help. I'll need to rescind this question.